# In apache kafka, how can we delete the content of _schemas topic without deleting the topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

In apache kafka, Is there any option delete the content of _schemas topic without deleting the topic and without changing the retention period to 1 sec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on answer by @cricket_007, Kafka internal topics __consumer_offsets and _schemas have compact cleanup policy by default.

If you want to alter the configuration just to delete, you can use `./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <host>:2181 --topic _schemas --alter --config cleanup.policy=delete`

Although both compact,delete policy is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2):

Well, the topic itself is set to `cleanup.policy=compact`, so retention does not apply.

If you want an empty topic, you should just reboot Registry with a different `kafkastore.topic` to create a new one

Otherwise, setting `cleanup.policy=compact,delete`, then something like `log.retention.ms=100`, will clean up the topic

Comment: Thanks for the response.